# CompileAssemblyFromSource throws Exception if service run as different user

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, .net-assembly

There is an application which compiles an assembly from source (in memory), but now I need to runs this application under an AD User **and** as a service. But this ends in an exception and I'm not able to fix this.

Use cases:

1. Running this app under my user -> Everything is fine
2. Running this app under a different user -> Exception
   File not found at `C:\Windows\TEMP\deij1sv4.0.cs` (This **can be fixed** by changing the EnvironmentVariable of TEMP)
3. Running this app under a different user and as a service -> Exception
   This **can not be fixed** by changing the EnvironmentVariable of TEMP)

### Code

Full sample: https://gist.github.com/dhcgn/13529f7f37174365fd96f8fcfb9a4eb4

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var asm = CreateInMemoryAssembly();
    dynamic foo = asm.CreateInstance("Foo");
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static Assembly CreateInMemoryAssembly()
{
    var code = "using System; public class Foo { public string Bar { get { return \"Hello!\"; } } }";

    var options = new CompilerParameters
    {
        CompilerOptions = "/t:library",
        GenerateInMemory = true,
        GenerateExecutable = false,
        IncludeDebugInformation = false,
        OutputAssembly = "TestAssembly.dll",
    };
    options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

    var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    CompilerResults result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, code);

    if (result.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        var msg = result.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().Aggregate(String.Empty, (current, error) => current + (error.ToString() + Environment.NewLine));
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }

    return result.CompiledAssembly;
}
```

### Exception

```
System.Exception: error CS2001: Die Quelldatei 'C:\Windows\TEMP\sesajnzr.0.cs' konnte nicht gefunden werden.
warning CS2008: Es wurden keine Quelldateien angegeben.

   bei TestConsole.Program.CreateInMemoryAssembly() in Program.cs:Zeile 51.
   bei TestConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:Zeile 19.
```

### Use of TempFiles

Thanks to the comment from @stuartd a tried to set the property `CompilerParameters.TempFiles`. If you review the code of [TempFileCollection.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/Common/src/System/IO/TempFileCollection.cs#L126) at CoreFx it seems like the right switch.

```
var tempDir = $@"C:\Temp\Temp_{Guid.NewGuid()}\";
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);
var tempFileCollection = new TempFileCollection(tempDir,true);
tempFileCollection.AddExtension("cs");

var options = new CompilerParameters
{
    CompilerOptions = "/t:library",
    GenerateInMemory = true,
    GenerateExecutable = false,
    IncludeDebugInformation = false,
    OutputAssembly = "TestAssembly.dll",
    TempFiles = tempFileCollection
};
```

#### Works with current user

[image]

#### Doesn't work with runas user

```
System.Exception: error CS1567: Fehler beim Generieren der Win32-Ressource: Zugriff verweigert
warning CS1610: Die temporäre Datei 'c:\Windows\System32\CSCEDE8DE40DD0A4ABBB937
A76D35F24C15.TMP', die für die Win32-Standardressource verwendet wird, kann nich
t gelöscht werden -- Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.

   bei TestConsole.Program.CreateInMemoryAssembly() in Program.cs:Zeile 58.
   bei TestConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:Zeile 20.
```

Comment: Please post the actual exception message.

Comment: I wonder if setting the [`TempFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.tempfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2) setting will make any difference? _"To specify a directory to generate unique temporary file names in, use an appropriately overloaded constructor. You can also use a constructor overload to indicate whether files added to the collection should, if not specified otherwise when using the AddFile or AddExtension methods, be deleted when the collection is disposed or the Delete method is called."_

Comment: @stuartd No. The property `TempFiles` doesn't change the behavior.